# How to draw simple Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I want to draw on the form on load in a C# program. Does the following code have to be in the `paint()` method? What does the `InitializeComponent()` do, exactly? what I was asking was what does the `InitializeComponent()` method do exactly. Basically I wasn't sure if there has to be an override on the `OnPaint()` method or if I can just draw where ever I want to put my code that will draw something on the form. The loadForm calls `DrawIt()` which will paint on the form. But that code for the paint is not in any specific `OnPaint()` or `Paint()` method.

```
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DrawIt()
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
               50, 50, 150, 150);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawIt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get yourself an introductory book on Winforms programming.  You are getting the basics very wrong, pretty hard to guess at it and intuition is not the best guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you should invoke your code in paint event. why must do that? I think paint event is invoked automatically by the windows when it is neccessary to update the form. if you invoke your code in form_load event, it is just invoked once, then when the form is showing, the form paints again, and it cover your effect in the form_load, so you can't see the result.
so, you can invoke your code in Form_paint() event or you can override OnPaint function, they are the same, like below:

```
private void DrawIt()
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
           50, 50, 150, 150);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
        this.Update();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawIt();
        base.OnPaint(e);

    }

    private void MainWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //DrawIt();
    }
```

result of my test is like this:
[image: result of drawing]

Comment: Does the protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawIt();
        base.OnPaint(e);

    }
onPaint just repaint the form when ever it should be repainted or when it needs to be repaitned. Can you just call onPaint() when you want to redraw the from. Why doesn't the above example cause an infinte loop because base.onPaint() you would think that it would just keep calling itself in a recursive call.

Comment: In my test app, it works well, doesn't cause infinite loop, what's the problem in your app?

Answer (score 1):

**InitializeComponent Method:**

When you create a form VS creates two file containing ONE class (just take a look at partial classes):

1) Form.cs which is where you put your code.

2) Form.Designer.cs which is the auto-generated partial class. when you put some component on your form in the design view, VS generates required codes to build that component at run-time in this class.

The `InitializeComponent` is an auto-generated method in Form.Designer.cs which initializes the components that you dropped on the form. When you call it from your constructor, you are just telling it to do the initialization when the form object is constructed.

**OnPaint Method:**

You should just put your drawing code in the `OnPaint` method. This method is called by .Net whenever it's required. for example if your window goes behind another window and then comes to the front again, your drawings are cleared! So this method is called again to re-paint the drawings.

Comment: In Java their is a repaint() that invokes paint() and a couple other painting methods. In VB.NET can this be done just in paint() and what if I wanted to repaint a custom component. Should I just redraw the whole form?

Comment: 1) Actually Paint is an Event not a Method. OnPaint is method that is triggerd when the Paint Event is raised. You can override OnPaint method or just attach your own method to the Paint Event.
2) Form class has inherited Paint and OnPaint from the Control class so you can do this with any Control that you want.
3) Note that controls and the form are redrawn anyway! you are just adding your custom code to the redraw procedure.

Comment: Do you have to override it like above

Comment: Inheriting from a Control is a little bit bothersome (eg. when you to use drag&drop in design view)! I think it is better to attach your own method to the Paint event of the Control like this:
`this.MyControl.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.MyControl_Paint)`

Comment: Could you show and example of this as a complete sub. I think I see what you mean but this.MyControl.Paint would already have to exist in the same file or another file, correct.

Comment: Just take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx